# Orika must have public setter

Tags: orika

I'm trying Orika and I'm wondering if you have to have public setter for the mapping to work ?

I tried without setter, it's not working, neither trying to explicitly tell byDefault() :

```
factory.classMap(Page.class, PageResource.class).byDefault().register();
```

any feedback on this one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default Orika configuration, mapped objects have to follow the JavaBean spec with getter/setter. Another possible way is, having public fields.

To change this behavior you can write your own `PropertyResolverStrategy` and configure it.

```
DefaultMapperFactory build = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder()
            .propertyResolverStrategy(new MyCustomPropertyResolvingStrategy())
            .build();
```

see the [documentation](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/extensibility.html) or the orika code for more information on this topic.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, seems it's quite complex to implements a custom property resolver using introspection to set value and not setters